# Should I use Flow as a return type in controller-based Spring Webflux service

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to make use of Kotlin `coroutines` along with `spring-data-r2dbc`(`databaseClient`) in our next Spring Boot service.
I'm already familiar with both concepts but as we dug deeper into the details of implementation I started to ask myself this question.

In most examples I saw, every endpoint that returned some sort of collections, will return Flow instead when migrating to reactive approach.

While there was no other(non-blocking) way to do it with `Mono`/`Flux`, since we wanted to hand over the subscription to the engine(`Webflux`), the situation is very different with Kotlin `Flows`. Flow's terminal operations are suspending, which makes them intrinsically non-blocking.
That means **I can terminate a Flow in a non-blocking way right when and where I get it**, and proceed with a regular `List`, for example.

Of course, there can be more complex scenarios with underlying hot publishers, reactive transports/protocols, etc., but in my case it's a very conventional service. The only reason we decided to use reactive approach is because it's IO-bound: for every API call, we will need to fetch data from multiple other services over HTTP/REST, then execute some database queries and then return the combined result.
So, the question is: does it make any sense to spatter Flow in multiple application layers(Controller, Service, Repository) if I can just reduce it to a regular `List` on the spot, say, in Repository:

```
    suspend fun findByEvent(id: String): List<MyEntity> =
        databaseClient.execute(MY_QUERY)....all().asFlow().toList()
```

so that the rest of my application layers won't even know anything about `Flow`(the entire chain of calls will remain suspendable anyway)?

Comment: any update to this?

Comment: Nope, haven't been using Kotlin since 2019, can't tell if there's more info about the usecases right now.